# i have started to have an issue in mongodump to create a dump for the entire database

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

My mongodump was working, but with the update for mongo for 4.4.

i started to have an issue.
{"plan":"database","next_run":"2020-11-04T23:00:00Z","last_run":"2020-11-03T23:00:00.000741156Z","last_run_status":"500","last_run_log":"Backup failed mongodump log 2020-11-03T23:00:00.073+0000\tFailed: error creating intents to dump: error creating intents for database config: error counting config.system.indexBuilds: (Unauthorized) not authorized on config to execute command { count: "system.indexBuilds", lsid: { id: UUID("cb4b038c-b9d7-4eab-86e0-fbbc142b43cd") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1604444395, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 60961DC390F0172EE83036301AEBA02FD558CED5), keyId: 6846331182976598018 } }, $db: "config", $readPreference: { mode: "primary" } } : exit status 1"}]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error.

```
Failed: error creating intents to dump: 
error creating intents for database config: 
error counting config.system.indexBuilds: 
(Unauthorized) not authorized on config to execute command 
{ count: "system.indexBuilds" .............
```

Seems, in my case, it was related to broken/buggy version of the mongodump itslef. I used the package `mongodb-tools` from `alpine:3.17.1` docker image.

When switched to Ubuntu and [downloaded latest](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools) version provided by the Mongo the problem disappeared.